# Is the wrong data type referenced?

Tags: delphi

When I write `GetLastError` and hit `Ctrl + Space` it get the hint popup.

[image: hint popup]

There are two `GetLastError`s. If I am correct, one is in `System.pas` and declared as `function GetLastError: Integer; {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS} stdcall; {$ENDIF}` and one is in `Winapi.Windows` declared as `function GetLastError: DWORD; stdcall;`

Where does the `Cardinal` data type come from? Case for Emba Support? What am I missing?

I have the `uses` of `interface` and `implementation` that are generated by a new `TForm`/Windows VCL Application - Delphi.

I am using Delphi 11 with Update 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where does the `Cardinal` data type come from?

[`DWORD`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Types.DWORD) is an alias for `Cardinal`. It is available in the `System` and `System.Types` units.

The popup is showing you the actual data types, not the aliased types.

Comment: FWIW this behavior has been fixed in Delphi 12 - the popup shows the types as declared in the signature and does not resolve aliases anymore. However, that is only the case for the popup being shown by `Ctrl + Space` - the tooltip shown when hovering over the method name unfortunately still resolves aliases.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `LongWord` instead of `Cardinal` in this case since I am on `MSWINDOWS`?

Comment: @complete_stranger the `GetLastError()` overload you are asking about returns a `DWORD`, which is an alias for `Cardinal` not `LongWord`. They are different types, even though they have the same size and value range.

Comment: In `Winapi.Windows` it's `DWORD = System.Types.DWORD;` -> in `Sytem.Types` it's `DWORD = FixedUInt;` in `System` it's `{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  FixedInt = LongInt;
  FixedUInt = LongWord;
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF POSIX}
  FixedInt = Integer;
  FixedUInt = Cardinal;
{$ENDIF}` hence my question. OS Windows, IDE Windows, Compile target Windows, everything Windows.